# JAX Random generator: random normal numbers, seem to be returned sorted and not completely random

Tags: python, machine-learning, random, statistics, jax

I'm trying to learn `jax` from 0. I've been trying to do some synthetic linear relationship data, so that

Y = B1*X + B0 + epsilon

My surprise has been that, when using the raw epsilons, the data seems to be ordered, so the points at the extremes get a higher error than the ones at the center. The shuffled version works fine, with errors normally distributed around the linear relationship

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import grad, jit, vmap
from jax import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 100
p = 2  # number of parameters including linear bias
key = random.PRNGKey(0)

X = random.uniform(key, (n, p - 1))
X = jnp.concatenate([jnp.ones((n, 1)), X], axis=1)
B = random.randint(key, (p, 1), 0, 10)

epsilon = random.normal(key, (n, 1))*0.3

y = X.dot(B) + epsilon
y_s = X.dot(B) + random.shuffle(key, epsilon)
plt.scatter(X[:,1], y, label='Original order')
plt.scatter(X[:,1], y_s, label='Shuffled')
plt.legend()
```

[image]
Why is this happening?

Comment: I don't know JAX well either, but by passing the same `key` each time, aren't you initiating each call to the random functions with the same PRNG state? Per the docs, *"Note that using a key does not modify it, so reusing the same key will lead to the same result"* - https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax.random.html#prng-keys. Obviously reusing the same key for `normal` and for `uniform` doesn't give literally the same distributions, but probably not surprising that the two sequences end up correlated.

Comment: @slothrop Bingo! that was the issue! If I create a new key, the problem is fixed. I still do not understand why, the key is the same but the distribution is not... time to read about how does this internally work!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're re-using the same random key three times, so your random draws are not independent. If you do this instead, you should get the results you expect:

```py
key1, key2, key3 = random.split(key, 3)

X = random.uniform(key1, (n, p - 1))
X = jnp.concatenate([jnp.ones((n, 1)), X], axis=1)
B = random.randint(key2, (p, 1), 0, 10)

epsilon = random.normal(key3, (n, 1))*0.3
```

JAX's random number generator is different than `numpy` and other tools in that it is not stateful, so you must explicitly generate additional keys when creating multiple independent streams. You can read more about this at [JAX Sharp Bits: Random Numbers](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#random-numbers).

If you're curious to read more of the design considerations behind this API, you might start with [JEP 263: JAX PRNG Design](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jep/263-prng.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the cause:
As @slothrop was pointing out, using the same key might yield some correlation. In the source code, you can see that it's basically applying a monotonic transformation to epsilon.

```
@partial(jit, static_argnums=(1, 2), inline=True)
def _normal_real(key, shape, dtype) -> jnp.ndarray:
  _check_shape("normal", shape)
  lo = np.nextafter(np.array(-1., dtype), np.array(0., dtype), dtype=dtype)
  hi = np.array(1., dtype)
  u = uniform(key, shape, dtype, lo, hi)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
  return np.array(np.sqrt(2), dtype) * lax.erf_inv(u)
```

The correlation coefficient is almost 1

```
jnp.corrcoef(X[:,1], epsilon)
```